# (Python) How to print something in a straight line

Tags: python, printing

I created the 'star' function to print triangle-shape stars.

I want to create 2 triangle stars next to each other like in this image:

[image]

But my function only prints one triangle star.

Only using 'star' function, How can i make 2 triangle stars?

```
s = ["*","* *","*****"]
def star(startpoint):   
     print(" "*(startpoint)+str(s[0]))
     print(" "*(startpoint-1)+str(s[1]))
     print(" "*(startpoint-2)+str(s[2]))

def star2(startpoint):
     print(" "*(startpoint)+str(s[0]),end='')
     print(" "*(startpoint+k)+str(s[0]))
     print(" "*(startpoint-1)+str(s[1]),end='')
     print(" "*(startpoint-1+k)+str(s[1]))
     print(" "*(startpoint-2)+str(s[2]),end='')
     print(" "*(startpoint-2+k)+str(s[2]))
```

I'd really appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to accomplish that with the `star` function you provided, but there is a way to greatly simplify the `star2` function:

```
def star(startpoint, num):
    s = ["*", "* *", "*****"]
    print(f"{' ' * startpoint}{s[0]}{' ' * startpoint}" * num)
    print(f"{' ' * (startpoint - 1)}{s[1]}{' ' * (startpoint - 1)}" * num)
    print(f"{' ' * (startpoint - 2)}{s[2]}{' ' * (startpoint - 2)}" * num)

star(3, 2)
```

Output:

```
   *      *   
  * *    * *  
 *****  *****
```

A few notes to what changes I made:

1. The `str()` wrapper around the `s[0]`, `s[1]` and `s[2]` aren't necessary, as each of its elements are already strings, so adding the `str()` wrapper only decreases efficiency.
2. It's better to define the `s` list *inside* the function, or make it an argument that needs to be passed into the brackets, or risk a bug if the list were to be altered elsewhere in your code.
3. Use `f` strings instead of constant concatenations for readability.
4. Finally, it is possible, but not very necessary for only three values, to use the built-in `enumerate()` method to iterate through the `s` list, instead of hard-coding its indices:

```
def star(startpoint, num):
    s = ["*", "* *", "*****"]
    for i, v in enumerate(s):
        print(f"{' ' * (startpoint - i)}{v}{' ' * (startpoint - i)}" * num)

star(3, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are, of course, multiple ways to solve your problem.

It might be easiest, not to print the triangle's characters directly.

Instead, I would buffer them in a list and print the resulting lines in the end.

I initialize the output buffer with `text = [[" " for _ in range(80)] for _ in range(5)]` and place the two triangles in this buffer by two calls of my `star` method.

```py
def star(lines, start_point, height, marker="*"):
    """
    Fill `lines` with a triangle

    :param lines: A list of list of strings
    :param start_point: The location of the triangle's top
    :param height: The height of the triangle
    :param marker: The character to use to write the triangle

    :return: `lines` for convenience, but editing happens inplace.
    """
    x1 = start_point[0]
    x2 = x1
    y = start_point[1]
    for i in range(height):
        lines[y][x1] = marker
        lines[y][x2] = marker
        y += 1
        x1 -= 1
        x2 += 1
    for x in range(x1, x2 + 1):
        lines[y][x] = marker

    return lines


if __name__ == '__main__':
    text = [[" " for _ in range(80)] for _ in range(5)]
    star(text, (10, 0), 2)
    star(text, (16, 0), 2)

    for line in text:
        print("".join(line))
```

**Output:**

```
      *     *                                                               
     * *   * *                                                              
    ***** *****
```

Note that you can easily change the location, height and markers of the triangles:

```
star(text, (10, 1), 2)
star(text, (20, 0), 4, "o")
```

Results in

```
                o                                                           
      *        o o                                                          
     * *      o   o                                                         
    *****    o     o                                                        
            ooooooooo
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code to draw n triangles next to each others:

```
def star(startpoint, n=1):
    s = ["  *   "," * *  ","***** "]
    print (startpoint*" "+n*str(s[0]))
    print (startpoint*" "+n*str(s[1]))
    print (startpoint*" "+n*str(s[2]))
     
star(15, 4)
```

Output is :

```
         *     *     *     *   
        * *   * *   * *   * *  
       ***** ***** ***** *****
```